# VPS with multiple ip and iptables

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

Is it so that when i have a VPS with Debian 8 (or whatever) and i order some extra ip's for it that that's not the same as adding networkinterfaces that can be treated that way by iptables?
eg.

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0:0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

would be nonsense?
From what i can see is that any rule that applies to eth0 also affects packets that are directed to another ip bound to the same interface like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address xxx.xxx.3.243
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway xxx.xxx.3.1

auto eth0:0

iface eth0:0 inet static

 address xxx.xxx.17.88

 netmask 255.255.255.0

 gateway xxx.xxx.3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my misunderstanding that acquiring extra ip with my VPS provider was the same as adding an extra NIC on the outside of the VM which is not the case.
Otherwise eth1 would have existed but eth0:1 is bound to that nic also.

Not suitable for an openvpn setup and it's obvious now how the traffic is treated.

Thanks for helping me out though! ;-)